# prefix column name to unnested struct in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large number of attributes under multiple structures in a dataset.
As a short example of the table:

| id | settings | tracking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {title:'who', 'values':'cares', size:10} | {website:'google', views:10, id:10} |

I want to unfold them all, so I do the following:

```
select settings.*, tracking.*, * except(settings, tracking)
from knowndataset
```

To which I would get something like:

| id | title | values | size | website | views | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'who' | 'cares' | 10 | 'google' | 10 | 10 |

The issue is that when the table is displayed, I don't know which attributes are coming from settings, and which from tracking, and which belong to the table. In addition, there could be column names that are repeated because of the unfolding.

Is there a way to prefix the column names with 'settings_' and 'tracking_', so that it is clear in the table where the attributes come from? I would like to do this without having to explicitly write out the code because there are several fields.

So what I'm looking for is:

| id | settings_title | settings_values | settings_size | tracking_website | tracking_views | tracking_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'who' | 'cares' | 10 | 'google' | 10 | 10 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the most generic approach I can think of!
Works for any number of structs, any level of nesting, etc.

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function get_leaves(input string) returns string language js as '''
  function flattenObj(obj, parent = '', res = {}){
    for(let key in obj){
        let propName = parent ? parent + '.' + key : key;
        if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
            flattenObj(obj[key], propName, res);
        } else {
            res[propName] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
  return flattenObj(JSON.parse(input));
  ''';
create temp table temp_table as (
  select offset, key, value, format('%t', t) row_id
  from your_table t, 
  unnest([struct(to_json_string(t) as json)]),
  unnest([struct(get_leaves(json) as leaves)]),
  unnest(get_keys(leaves)) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(leaves)) value with offset
  using(offset) 
);  

execute immediate (
  select '''
    select * except(row_id) from (select * except(offset) from temp_table)
    pivot (any_value(value) for replace(key, '.', '_') in (''' || keys || "))"
  from (
    select string_agg('"' || replace(key, '.', '_') || '"', ',' order by offset) keys 
    from (select key, min(offset) as offset from temp_table group by key)
  )
);
```

if apply to dummy data as in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be practical, but technically below approach can be applicable to limited use cases.(i.e. a permanent table, not a temp table or a subquery)

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT 'CREATE TEMP TABLE struct_schema (' || STRING_AGG(new_field) || ');'
    FROM `testset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`,
  UNNEST (REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(data_type, r'(\w+ \w+)') field,
  UNNEST ([column_name || '_' || SPLIT(field, ' ')[OFFSET(0)] || ' ' || SPLIT(field, ' ')[OFFSET(1)]]) new_field
   WHERE column_name IN ('settings', 'tracking')
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT 'CREATE TEMP TABLE non_struct_schema (' || STRING_AGG(new_field) || ');'
    FROM `testset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`,
  UNNEST ([column_name || ' ' || data_type]) new_field
   WHERE column_name NOT IN ('settings', 'tracking')
);

SELECT * FROM non_struct_schema, struct_schema
 UNION ALL
SELECT * EXCEPT(settings, tracking), settings.*, tracking.*
  FROM `testset.knowndataset`;
```

output will be:

[image]

with sample dataset:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testset;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `testset.knowndataset` AS
SELECT 1 AS id,
       STRUCT('who' AS title, 'cares' AS values, 10 AS size) AS settings,
       STRUCT('google' AS website, 10 AS views, 10 AS id) AS tracking;
```